# Как создать очередь/стэк/дэк/вектор из функций?

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, контейнеры

есть некоторые функции:

```
void f(int i){}
void f(int i, int j){}
void f(){}
void h(double d){}
```

в ходе работы программы мне становится нужно запустить эту функцию с какими-то конкретными параметрами, затем с другими, потом вообще без параметров. но я хочу выполнить их не сейчас, а позже.
поэтому мне нужно создать список,например, такой:
запусти f(4), затем f(0,5), затем f(), затем h(2.5).
по окончанию работы по составлению списка нужно запустить эти функции с заданными параметрами.
как мне добавить эти функции в std::vector и при этом не создавать отдельно список входящих переменных, а сразу делать указатель на функцию с заданными параметрами?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если параметры функций известны заранее, то вот так:

```
std::vector<void(*)()> vec;
vec.push_back([]{f(10, 20);});
```

Если нет, то так:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> vec;
int a = ..., b = ...;
vec.push_back([=]{f(a, b);});
```

Здесь нужны `std::function` вместо указателей на функцию, потому что лямбды с непустым списком захвата `[...]` в указатели не преобразуются.

Comment: в квадратных скобках, насоклько я понимаю, список передаваемых переменных (копии). а что даёт знак равенства там же? и как мне потом вызывать эти функции, если параметры были указаны при добавлении в вектор? vec[index](/*тут пусто*/) -- так?

Comment: @nekaro8901 Знак равенства говорит автоматически копировать в лямбду все нужные переменные. Здесь вместо него можно было написать `a,b`. *"vec[index](/*тут пусто*/) -- так?"* Ага.

Comment: а если я хочу передать все переменные, но не копии, а по ссылке, то так? `v.push_back([&=]{f(a,b);});`

Comment: @nekaro8901 `v.push_back([&]{f(a,b);});`.

Comment: и ещё вопрос: если я проведу проверку на равенство в таком векторе, то как оно будет работать и будет ли? скажем, if (vec.back() != vec.front()) что будет сравнивать? указатели на функцию или void с void-ом(значения возвращаемых типов данных)?

Comment: @nekaro8901 В первом случае указатели на функцию, да. А для `std::function` не скомпилируется.

Comment: vec.push_back(&[&]{f(a, b);}); -- добавит в std::vector функцию по ссылке, которая принимает аргументы по ссылке, верно? или такое невозможно сделать с лямбда-выражением?

Comment: @nekaro8901 Лямбда-выражение создает временный объект, так что его адрес взять нельзя. Да и зачем?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать прелести инкапсуляции и хранить данные (аргументы функции) и методы (непосредственно функции) внутри одного объекта. Это позволит реализовать ряд функционала более естественным образом. Например:

```
#include <vector>

class Command
{
public:
    virtual void command() =0;
};

class ConcreteCommand_1 : public Command
{
public:
    ConcreteCommand_1(int);
    void command() override;
protected:
    int arg1_;
    void f(int);
};

class ConcreteCommand_2 : public Command
{
public:
    ConcreteCommand_2(int, int);
    void command() override;
protected:
    int arg1_;
    int arg2_;
    void f(int, int);
};


ConcreteCommand_1::ConcreteCommand_1(int arg1) : arg1_(arg1) {}
void ConcreteCommand_1::command()
{
    f(arg1_);
}

ConcreteCommand_2::ConcreteCommand_2(int arg1, int arg2) : arg1_(arg1), arg2_(arg2) {}
void ConcreteCommand_2::command()
{
    f(arg1_, arg2_);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<Command*> operations;

    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_1(3));
    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_1(1));
    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_1(0));

    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_2(0, 1));
    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_2(1, 1));
    operations.push_back(&ConcreteCommand_2(2, -4));

    for (Command* c : operations) c->command();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выходит, каждый раз, когда я захочу добавить в список возможных функций новую функцию, то мне будет нужно описывать дочерний класс или дополнительный конструктор. даст ли это прирост скорости в работе по сравнению с вариантом выше?

Comment: @nekaro8901, не думайте об оптимизации раньше времени. Этот приём даст вам прирост в скорости разработки и расширит возможности, не нужно будет думать над костылями для сложных решений. Кроме того, я описал лишь пример, вы можете заложить больше логики в базовый класс.

Comment: Нельзя брать адрес временного объекта. Но даже если компилятор это разрешил (привет, MSVC), в векторе останутся висячие ссылки на мертвые объекты.

Comment: Это не больше, чем просто пример.